# Need help authenticating to Okta programatically

Tags: slack, slack-api, okta, okta-api, okta-signin-widget

here's some background of what I'm trying to do. I do not have admin access to my organization Okta enterprise. What I'm trying to do is to login to Okta programatically, and then subsequently login to Slack via Okta SSO so that I can grab the access token. The reason for this is all authentication/authorization is hidden behind Okta, and I want this Slack access token to retrieve my own Slack message so that I can create custom scripts to retrieve, write message on behalf of myself.

Note that all I have is my own username and password credentials with MFA.

I have tried the following.

1. Login to Okta via browser programatically using [go-rod](https://github.com/go-rod/rod). Which I managed to do so successfully, but I'm failing to load up Slack as it's stuck in the browser loader screen for Slack.
2. I tried to authenticate via Okta RESTful API. So far, I have managed to authenticate using `{{domain}}/api/v1/authn`, and then subsequently using MFA via the verify endpoint `{{domain}}/api/v1/authn/factors/{{factorID}}/verify` which returns me a `sessionToken`. From here, I can successfully create a sessionCookie which have proven quite useless to me. Perhaps I am doing it wrongly.

I'd like to expand deeper into Approach #2. I still haven't figured out the exact way to authenticate to Slack programatically via SSO. All I have at this point is

- Username
- Password
- MFA
- SessionToken

  - Follow through into `{{domain}}/api/v1/sessions` which returns me

    - id
    - userId
    - idp

      - id
      - type
        etc
- SessionCookie (Useless?)

I'm pretty much stuck here. I don't have a client_id/client_secret. I have been playing around with `/oauth/v1/token` and `/oauth/v1/authorize` but with disappointing results.

I even tried using this CLI package (https://github.com/oktadev/pkce-cli) but I'm just getting 400 bad request with the authorize URL generated. So I know I'm doing something wrong for sure.

Any help is appreciated! I have spent days to weeks on this.

Comment: Still not very clear about your intentions: so you want to get an authentication as Slack User via SSO like you do that in browser, and after that do actions in Slack like you do that in a browser? Like for some Selenium/scriptable browser clicker?

I'm not sure this is a valid case to use this for, however per my research using of undocumented methods not available in official API but available via web client is possible with Bearer token `xoxc-**` and a browser Cookie `d=xoxd-**` which are obtained somehow if logging in the browser, suppose documented work similarly.

Comment: Just checked how the Google SSO login works: after sending the Google creds and bunch of internal redirects it redirects to the https://slack.com/sso/google, which responds with set up of the clients cookies with `set-cookie` headers, and after that when Slack downloads web client, https://app.slack.com/auth call is made that returns `xoxc-**` token. Perhaps you should do some similar calls while authenticating? However seems these all are undocumented calls, convenient to create and install app with scopes and obtain user token while installing this app.